# JNI load class problem

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to load class from a jar. If i add the required jar in VM Options then i am able to load any class from that jar.

```
JavaVMOption options[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=xyz.jar";
```

Whereas if i include the jar path in system environment variable (CLASSPATH) then unable to load any class from that jar; even though its part of classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the JVM you're responsible for setting up the class path - *you* need to read the environment variable and pass it to `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. `JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs` *may* set this up for you, but you'll need to call it and pass the init args to `JNI_CreateJavaVM`

Comment: Tried JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs but still is not picking the jar; which are part of classpath but if i read the environment variable and pass it to InitArgs things start working.

Comment: @Asoo: IIRC an older JVM did pick up the classpath when you called JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs, but the newer ones don't

Comment: I think best way is to read the environment variable and pass it to InitArgs

Comment: @Asoo: Yep, that's the safe solution